# multiple robots under one core?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm planning to use multiple turtlebots under the same core. The thing is that, for example, all the robots uses the same name for the topics. My question is:
Is it possible to modifying a little bit the code I get different names for each robot or do I need to manually go through all the code and change all the names of the nodes?

What I want is to get something like, instead of cmd_vel turtlebot1/cmd_vel, instead of joy turtlebot1/joy and so on.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12650/multiple-robots-under-one-core?/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to push the TurtleBots into their own namespaces.. so when you launch the TurtleBots do something like this in your rolsaunch file

```
<launch>
  <group ns=turtlebot1>

    all your regular launch stuff.....

  </group>
</launch>
```

see this page for more roslaunch XML markup help
http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-01-16**:
Maybe, also set tf_prefix to the robot name.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you mwise_wg, it's been really usefull.

Only thing to coment is that the correct command is < group ns="turtlebot1"> and < /group> instead of ns and /ns.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) with karma: 318 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1